# How to autorun Perl after killed?

Tags: perl, autorun

I have script that use multiple $pid. So if too many connection of child spawn, my server hang and program not running.

I want to restart it automatic from cron job at my server, but it's cannot running because I use alternatif cPanel. So I want restart it automatic from it script.

I try to restart it with :

```
 kill 9, $pid;    
 sleep 60;
```

and will display output :

```
Child Spawned : 15945

Killed
```

But I don't know  how to autorun or re-execute

Answer (score 3):

It looks you want a per-forking worker pool. Your server process starts a number of child processes to handle requests, and automatically restarts any that die.

A basic template:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(sigprocmask SIG_BLOCK SIG_UNBLOCK SIGINT SIGTERM WNOHANG);

my $pool_size = 4;  # 4 workers
my %pool;

# When one or more workers die, delete them from the pool
$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    while ((my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
        delete $pool{$pid};
    }
};

# If a fatal signal is sent to the server, kill all children and exit
for my $sig (qw(INT TERM)) {
    $SIG{$sig} = sub {
        local $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
        kill $sig => keys %pool;
        exit;
    };
}

# HUP = restart all workers
$SIG{HUP} = sub {
    print "Caught HUP, restarting workers.\n";
    kill TERM => keys %pool
};

# Set up pool
make_worker() for (1..$pool_size);

# Maintain population
while (1) {
    sleep;  # wait for signal
    while (keys %pool < $pool_size) {
        make_worker();
    }
}

exit;

sub make_worker {
    # Block INT signal during fork, so parent handler is not called
    my $sigset = POSIX::SigSet->new(SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, $sigset) or die "Couldn't block signals for fork: $!";
    my $pid = fork;
    die "fork: $!" if !defined $pid;
    if ($pid) {
        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, $sigset) or die "Couldn't unblock signals for fork: $!";
        $pool{$pid} = 1;
        return;
    }
    else {
        $SIG{$_} = 'DEFAULT' for qw(INT TERM);
        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, $sigset) or die "Couldn't unblock signals for child: $!";

        # Your worker code goes here.

        exit;
    }
}
```

---

For simply restarting a single command in a loop, try;

```
while(1) {
    system("/path/to/your-command", "--args");
}
```

As soon as the command dies (for any reason), it is re-executed. Processing the exit code of system is not that simple, so I recommend using IPC::System::Simple here.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system);
use Try::Tiny;

while(1) {
    try { system(...) } 
    catch { "Command failed, restarting: $!" };
}
```

You should also detect if the command exited too quickly, which would indicate a fatal error.